# Newly added nodes showing as DN to each other in nodetool status output

Tags: cassandra

I have recently installed Cassandra 4.1.1 in 5 node onPremise Cluster for my production environment..
For testing purpose I just added two seed nodes in Config file and restarted the Server and service below is the status of Nodetool after that

In B server

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
>Status=Up/Down\
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving\
--  Address      Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack\
DN  XXX.XX.XX.A  208.51 KiB  16      100.0%            8b141431-7421-4d13-919d-d88a4fea7649  rack1\
UN  XXX.XX.XX.B  239.76 KiB  16      100.0%            0025f537-35c8-48ba-92b3-cfdfaee78a99  rack1
```

In A server

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
>Status=Up/Down\
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving\
--  Address      Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack\
UN  XXX.XX.XX.A  208.51 KiB  16      100.0%            8b141431-7421-4d13-919d-d88a4fea7649  rack1\
DN  XXX.XX.XX.B  239.76 KiB  16      100.0%            0025f537-35c8-48ba-92b3-cfdfaee78a99  rack1
```

Dont Know how to fix this and Now server has no data am about to load it..

Below are the GossipInfo status

```
nodetool gossipinfo
/XXX.XX.XX.B
  generation:1684942657
  heartbeat:1319
  LOAD:1313:213518.0
  SCHEMA:13:54e17321-3f2e-37ca-9b08-d91ba7bdd369
  DC:9:datacenter1
  RACK:11:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:4.1.1
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:8b141431-7421-4d13-919d-d88a4fea7649
  RPC_READY:31:true
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:XXX.XX.XX.B:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:1213:NORMAL,-2221626050107619877
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:1212:<hidden>
/XXX.XX.XX.A
  generation:1684940942
  heartbeat:2950
  STATUS:2908:NORMAL,-1567249714150872921
  LOAD:2928:243794.0
  SCHEMA:13:54e17321-3f2e-37ca-9b08-d91ba7bdd369
  DC:9:datacenter1
  RACK:11:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:4.1.1
  RPC_ADDRESS:5:XXX.XX.XX.A
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:0025f537-35c8-48ba-92b3-cfdfaee78a99
  RPC_READY:31:true
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:XXX.XX.XX.A:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:2907:NORMAL,-1567249714150872921
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:2906:<hidden>
```

Kindly help me out in this regard

Answer (score 0):

The down/normal (`DN`) status is an indication that the nodes cannot gossip with each other.

If there is a firewall in between them, make sure that bi-directional TCP traffic on the gossip port (default is `7000`) is open.

Otherwise, you will need to do some investigation as to why they are showing as `DN` by reviewing the logs. Without knowing the reason, it will be hard for anyone to help you. Cheers!